# How can I show the data that comes with SQL as a multi-group list in the html page?

Tags: javascript, html

After getting the data with sql query, I can show it as a list on the html page. But I want to show the data as a list by grouping it. You can look at the image file for how it should look.

DATASET:

```
| Column A | Column B  |Column C    |Column D |
MAN         FRUIT       BANANA       10
MAN         FRUIT       STRAWBERRY   15
MAN         BREAKFAST   BUTTER       20
MAN         VEGETABLE   CARROT       10
WOMAN       FRUIT       BANANA        5
WOMAN       BREAKFAST   BUTTER       20
WOMAN       BREAKFAST   CHEESE        5
```

**The list I want to see with grouping instead of a flat list is like in the picture**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZH1r.png)

I am using below code for flat list.
JS CODE:

```
 function TESTTT($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
        var serializedData = $.param({user:postUserName,password:postPassword,datasetName:'TEST_dATA',parameters:'X:\''+kullaniciNet+'\''});
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: postUrl,
            data: serializedData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }}).then(function(result) {

            $scope.TESTT =  [
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA ",Column_D:10}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "STRAWBERRY ", Column_D:15},
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER",Column_D:20}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "VEGETABLE", Column_C:  "CARROT", Column_D:10},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA", Column_D:5}, 
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER", Column_D:20},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "CHEESE", Column_D:5}
    ];
            
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
    $scope.getData();

}
```

HTML CODE.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet-body" ng-controller="TESTTT">
        <div id="sample_1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
            <div class="scroller table-responsive" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 750px;">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
                
                    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center;font-weight:600;font-size:1em;">
                        1
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;font-weight:600;font-size:1em;">
                        2
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;font-weight:600;font-size:1em;">
                        3
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;font-weight:600;font-size:1em;">
                        4
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="TEST in TESTT" class="ng-scope">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="ng-binding" style="text-align:left;">
                            {{TEST.Column_A}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="ng-binding">
                            {{TEST.Column_B }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="ng-binding">
                            {{TEST.Column_C}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="ng-binding">
                            {{TEST.Column_D }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can loop through the results of your query, and keep nesting the objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of dealing with this. For example, we could use a simple `for` loop combined with remapping the original keys to what we want to have.

Or we could reduce and remap the array to an object.

If I'm not misunderstanding your intention, your expected result, based on the image you posted, would look like this.

```
{
    "Man" : {
        "Fruit" : {
            "Banana": 10,
            "Strawberry": 15
        },
        "Breakfast" : {
            "Butter": 20,
            "Carrot": 10
        }
    },
    "Woman" : {
        "Fruit": {
            "Banana" : 5
        },
        "Breakfast" : {
            "Butter" : 20,
            "Cheese" : 5
        }
    }
}
```

If you're always going to have four columns (A-D) in your query results, you could loop through the object, until you reach the third level (Breakfast / Fruit / etc), and create your HTML table columns / rows from that.

Some notes before we begin - I'll only be presenting the JS part of remapping your initial data.

Let's see what we can do to get the end result to look like the one I mentioned earlier (again, if I have not misunderstood your intention). There will be explanations along the way, but if it feels like I'm ranting, skip through to the code, and test it, to see if it fits what you need.

---

#### JS solution #1 - regular `for` loop

```js
var data = [
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA ",Column_D:10}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "STRAWBERRY ", Column_D:15},
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER",Column_D:20}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "VEGETABLE", Column_C:  "CARROT", Column_D:10},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA", Column_D:5}, 
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER", Column_D:20},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "CHEESE", Column_D:5}
];

// This is where we'll be storing our results
var results = {};

// Let's loop through
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let columnA = data[i].Column_A; // Man, Woman, etc
    let columnB = data[i].Column_B; // fruit, breakfast, etc
    let columnC = data[i].Column_C; // Banana, Strawberry, etc
    let columnD = data[i].Column_D; // 10, 15, etc

    if(typeof results[columnA] === 'undefined') {
        results[columnA] = {};
    }
    if(typeof results[columnA][columnB] === 'undefined') {
        results[columnA][columnB] = {};
    }
    results[columnA][columnB][columnC] = columnD;
}
console.log(results);
```

For convenience's sake, I've renamed your `$scope.TESTT` variable to `data`, and filled it with the same data you get from your query.

`results` is initially an empty object, which we'll be filling up as we go.

Since `data` is an array of objects, and the objects have a known depth and number of keys, we can employ a simple `for` loop to sift through, and repack our data.

After defining our helper variables (`columnA`-`columnD`), we check if there's anything in the first level of our `results` object. If it's our first run through the loop, nothing will be there, and that's why we need the `if` / `undefined` check - we're basically setting the first level key, if it's not already there.

We're also doing this for the second key (whatever's in the `columnB`), and for the same reason.

Lastly, since there are only two levels left, and one of them should be our next key, we can simply do

```
results[columnA][columnB][columnC] = columnD;
                          ^__ we're setting this now
                 ^__ this has been set
        ^__ this has been set
```

Now, this solution works for the given case. If you have have more than four columns, you'd have to change it, and that would lead to additional problems - repetition. Also, try and play with the columns - have one of your array elements have less than four columns, or more than four columns, while leaving the others at four columns, just to see what would happen.

You could avoid repetition by using functions and recursion, or you could go with the next solution.

---

#### JS solution #2 - `Array.reduce`

```js
var data = [
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA ",Column_D:10}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B: "FRUIT", Column_C:  "STRAWBERRY ", Column_D:15},
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER",Column_D:20}, 
    { Column_A:"MAN", Column_B:  "VEGETABLE", Column_C:  "CARROT", Column_D:10},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "FRUIT", Column_C:  "BANANA", Column_D:5}, 
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "BUTTER", Column_D:20},
    { Column_A:"WOMAN", Column_B:  "BREAKFAST", Column_C:  "CHEESE", Column_D:5}
];

// Let's get all of the colums, regardless of how many
// of them are there - we still need them to be the same
// between the elements of your initial data array
var columns = Object.keys(data[0]);

// acc - where we're storing the processed elements
// of the data array
// curr - the element of the data array we're currently
// processing, and later inserting into arr object
var results = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  var temp = acc;
  
  // we still need the for loop, but this time
  // what's inside of it is dynamic
  // since we know the last two levels should be 
  // in key : value format, our for loop should
  // stop before it reaches them
  for(var i = 0; i < columns.length-2; i++){
      // just for debugging, and so we can understand better
      console.log("inside", columns[i]);
      let key = curr[columns[i]];
      console.log("key is: " + key); 
      if(!temp[key]) {
        temp[key] = {};
      }
      console.log("tmp key is: " + JSON.stringify(temp[key]));
      temp = temp[key];
      console.log(" .... .... .... ");
  }
  console.log("ending the loop...");
  
  // finally, once outside of the loop, we pair up the
  // last two columns / levels, and add them to temp
  temp[curr[columns[columns.length-2]]] = curr[columns[columns.length-1]];
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(results);
```

While this method works for an unknown number of columns, like the first one, it supposes that the columns will have the same structure among the objects, and that the last pair of columns will always be displayed like you've shown in your screenshot.

This isn't that far removed from reality - you are controlling the query, after all, and can have a say in how the DB output is presented.

---

Now, between the two methods of dealing with this, I prefer the first one, since the number of columns is known beforehand, and so is the structure. A couple of tests on [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/o8lcuyfev2/1) show that the second solution is also somewhat slower.